# Routes not processed

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've got a node.js (server) and backbone.js (client) app - I can load and init my backbone app on a page... and init the router, but my default route (".*") is not getting called. I can manually call the index function after I initialize the router, but I don't have to take that step when I've built backbone apps over rails.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

adding code (in coffeescript):

```
class NodeNetBackbone.Routers.RegistryPatients extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    ''          : 'index'
    '.*'        : 'index'
    '/index'    : 'index'
    '/:id'      : 'show'
    '/new'      : 'new'
    '/:id/edit' : 'edit'

  initialize: ->
    console.log 'init the router'
    @registry_patients = new NodeNetBackbone.Collections.RegistryPatients()
    # TODO: Figure out why this isn't sticking...
    @registry_patients.model = NodeNetBackbone.Models.RegistryPatient
    # TODO: Try to only round trip once on initial load
    # @registry_patients.reset($('#container_data').attr('data'))
    @registry_patients.fetch()

    # TODO: SSI - why are the routes not getting processed?
    this.index()

  index: ->
    console.log 'made it to the route index'
    view = new NodeNetBackbone.Views.RegistryPatients.Index(collection: @registry_patients)
    # $('#container').html('<h1>Patients V3: (Backbone):</h1>')
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of how you are defining your routes?

Comment: without code examples we can't see what could be fixed so please provide your code

Comment: Well, I'm just gonna go on a hunch, but, the default route is not `'*.'`. It's only `''` (an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Backbone routes are not regexes (unless you manually add a regex route using `route`). From the [fine manual](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-routes):

> Routes can contain parameter parts, `:param`, which match a single URL component between slashes; and splat parts `*splat`, which can match any number of URL components.
>
> [...] A route of `"file/*path"` will match `#file/nested/folder/file.txt`, passing `"nested/folder/file.txt"` to the action.

And if we check the source, [we'll see this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L784):

```
// Backbone.Router
// -------------------
//...
// Cached regular expressions for matching named param parts and splatted
// parts of route strings.
var namedParam    = /:\w+/g;
var splatParam    = /\*\w+/g;
```

So your `'.*'` route should only match a literal `'.*'` rather than matching "anything" as you're expecting.

I think you want something more like this:

```
routes:
  ''          : 'index'
  #...
  '*path'     : 'index'
```

Make sure your `*path` route is at [the bottom of your route list](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L818):

```
// Bind all defined routes to `Backbone.history`. We have to reverse the
// order of the routes here to support behavior where the most general
// routes can be defined at the bottom of the route map.
```

This assumption about the "order" of elements in an object seems rather dangerous and ill-considered to me as [there is no guaranteed order](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4):

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

I think you'd be better off adding your default `*path` route manually in your `initialize` method:

```
class NodeNetBackbone.Routers.RegistryPatients extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    ''          : 'index'
    '/index'    : 'index'
    '/:id'      : 'show'
    '/new'      : 'new'
    '/:id/edit' : 'edit'

  initialize: ->
    console.log 'init the router'
    @route '*path', 'index'
    #...
```